# C++ I want to do something like Class1.Class2.Fct()

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ programming and I need your help:

Let's say I have a class - Class1. Is it possible to have another class (Class2) with (at least) one function that returns (for example) an integer? Here is an example with I want to achive:

```
std::cout << "I did it: " << Class1.Class2.ReturnINTEGER() << std::endl;
```

I need the code to be compatible with GNU G++ compiler. Thanks :).

Comment: I think you need a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to get you started on how to do just that.

Comment: You don't put class names before `.`, you put variables whose type is the class.

Comment: `.` separates a variable (or other expression that returns a struct or class object) from a member name in the class.

Comment: I think that you might be right, @Rakete1111 - but do you know the answer or anything like this?

Comment: @VVICAndC15 Sure, but start to learn classes, and you will see that it is really easy to do that :)

Comment: Come on - if you know the answer just say it :/ @Rakete1111

Comment: There is no answer because the question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.  Let's dissect or rebuild.
First to get `Class1.Class2`, we need to have a class *member* called `Class2`.   And `Class2` needs to have a member called `Fct`.

Here is one implementation:

```
struct Class2_Object
{
  void Fct(void);
};

struct Class1_Object
{
  Class2_Object Class2;
};

Class1_Object Class1;
Class1.Class2.Fct();
```

Comment: This one helps - thanks a lot :))

Comment: Please don't use `void` to specify that no arguments should be passed to `Fct`, it is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Rakete1111: Although unnecessary *in C++*, it is allowable, and a carry over from the C language.  I'm presently programming in both languages, but on different projects.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but as this is a C++ question, I think it is better to answer in C++, and not in C

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Two
{
public:
    int toReturn;
    Two()
    {
        toReturn=0;
    }

    int returnValue() 
    {
         return toReturn;
    } 
};

class One
{
 public:
     Two foo;
};

int main() 
{
    One bar;
    int toPrint=bar.foo.returnValue();
    cout << toPrint << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ok - i tried to solve the errors - here:

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Two
{
public:
    int toReturn;

    Two()
    {
      toReturn=0;
    }

    int returnValue()
    {
      return toReturn;
    }
};

class One
{
public:
   Two foo;
};

int main()
{
    One bar;
    int toPrint=bar.foo.returnValue();
    cout << toPrint << endl;
}